# Emacs: regular expression replacing to change case

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

Every once in a while I want to replace all instances of values like:

```
<BarFoo>
```

with

```
<barfoo>
```

i.e. do a regular expression replace of all things inside angle brackets with its lowercase equivalent.

Anyone got a nice snippet of Lisp that does this? It's safe to assume that we're dealing with just ASCII values. Bonus points for anything that is generic enough to take a full regular expression, and doesn't just handle the angle brackets example. Even more bonus points to an answer which just uses `M-x query-replace-regexp`.

Thanks,

Dom

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try `M-x query-replace-regexp` with `"<\([^>]+\)>"` as the search string and `"<\,(downcase \1)>"` as the replacement.

This should work for Emacs 22 and later, see this [Steve Yegge blog post](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/06/shiny-and-new-emacs-22.html) for more details on how Lisp expressions can be used in the replacement string.

For earlier versions of Emacs you could try something like this:

```
(defun tags-to-lower-case ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "<[^>]+>" nil t)
      (replace-match (downcase (match-string 0)) t))))
```

Comment: That's cool! I wasn't aware of \,() in Emacs regular expressions.

Comment: This gets me the error "Invalid use of `\' in replacement text"

Comment: Regexp should be "<\\([^>]+\\)>" and the replacement doesn't work as expected if the search string matches tag in all caps.

Comment: I've edited the answer so that the backslashes in the search expression are now visible.

Comment: Ah - that's probably why it didn't work, I'm running Emacs 21.2.1 - any other ideas?

Comment: Emacs can handle .*? as a non-greedy match.

Comment: Re: This gets me the error "Invalid use of `\' in replacement text" - if you are editing a previous command via redo (M-x esc esc), you'll get this, because the M-x query-replace-regexp command appears to replace \,() with the actual lisp expression.  If you run M-x query-replace-regexp, you can use \,() in the replacement expression.

Comment: @emk Indeed! It's not even mentioned on the [Emacs regexp wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)!

Comment: Nice!  @LukeGirvin is it possible to use this is in a multibuffer workflow?  I was able to use it for a single buffer but trying to use 'U' for multibuffers in IBuffer mode resulted in the dreaded "Invalid use of `\' in replacement text"  -- I tried various escaping to no avail.

Comment: I just used this and it works. But, I wonder why the `\,` construct. Does it have a precedence from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is ancient, but I just discovered how to do this in Emacs **before** version 22 (my version is 21.3.1) without the need for defining a custom Lisp function: use `M-x query-replace-regexp-eval` (mentioned at the top of [this Emacs wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplaceRegexpWithLispExpressions)) with `<\([^>]+\)>` as the search string and `(concat "<" (downcase \1) ">")` as the replacement.

This should work with any replacement string that can be defined as a concatenation of parts, including captured groups not modified by any function.  For example:

```
<BarFoo baz="Quux">
```

can have just the tag name downcased:

```
<barfoo baz="Quux">
```

by using search string `<\([A-Za-z]+\)\([^>]*\)>` and replacement `(concat "<" (downcase \1) \2 ">")` (which also works on OP's example that looks like a tag with no attributes).

Answer (score 0):

When using evil, you can simply do `:%s/<\([^>]+\)>/<\L\1>`

`\L` is responsible for lowercasing all following letters, this should also work for `query-replace-regexp`.

I have not found documentation around Emacs for that, but it seems to match this list: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html