# Case conversion of file name (regexp) in Emacs file browser

Tags: regex, emacs, dired, case-conversion

I have a similar problem to that addressed in

[Emacs: regular expression replacing to change case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677021/emacs-regular-expression-replacing-to-change-case)

I want to use Emacs' file browser mode Dired to rename a file from `08 - hey you.mp3` to `08 - Hey you.mp3`.

I type `% R` to replace `^\([0-9]* - \)\([a-z]\)\(.*\)$` by `\1\,(upcase \2)\3` and I get an error

```
Invalid use of `\' in replacement text
```

When I query-replace-regexp a similar regexp `\([0-9]* - \)\([a-z]\)\(.*\)` by `\1\,(upcase 2)\3` in a normal text buffer I don't have problems. The only input difference are the enclosing `^` and `$`, that are required as explained in http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transforming-File-Names.html#Transforming-File-Names, however the source of error seems to be the `\,(upcase )`, which seems not usable in Dired, since I don't have this error when I use for example `\1\3\2`as replace regexp.

I am using Emacs 23.2.1

Answer (score 2):

`% R` in dired calls `dired-do-rename-regexp` which ends up calling `replace-match` from `dired-string-replace-match`, and replace-match does not support elisp replacements.

What you can do is take advantage of `wdired` which allows you to edit the directory listing as plain text.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> (i.e. the usual `toggle-read-only` binding) will toggle between dired and wdired. Once in wdired, you can use a normal search and replace, including the elisp replacement pattern.