# Emacs: regular expression replacing to change case (in scripts)

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

This is related to
[Emacs: regular expression replacing to change case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677021/emacs-regular-expression-replacing-to-change-case)

My additional problem is that I need to script the search-replace but the `"\,()"` solution works (for me) only when used interactively `(emacs 24.2.1)`. Inside a script it gives the error: "Invalid use of `\'` in replacement text".

I usually write a "perform-replace" to some file to be loaded when needed. Something like:
(perform-replace `"<\\([^>]+\\)>"  "<\\,(downcase \1)>"` t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))

It should be possible to call a function to generate the replacement `(pg 741 of the emacs lisp manual)`, but I've tried many variations of the following with no luck:

```
(defun myfun ()
    (downcase (match-string 0)))

(perform-replace "..." (myfun . ()) t t nil)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Constructs like `\,()` are only allowed in interactive calls to `query-replace`, which is why Emacs complains in your case.

The documentation of `perform-replace` mentions that you should not use it in elisp code and proposes a better alternative, upon which we can build the following code:

```
(while (re-search-forward "<\\([^>]+\\)>" nil t)
  (replace-match (downcase (match-string 0)) t nil))
```

---

If you still want to interactively query the user about the replacements, using `perform-replace` like you did is probably the right thing to do. There were a few different problems in your code:

1. As stated in the [elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html) the replacement function must take two arguments (the data you provide in the cons cell and the number  of replacements already made).
2. As stated in the documentation of `query-replace-regexp` (or the [elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Case.html#Searching-and-Case)), you need to ensure that `case-fold-search` or `case-replace` is set to nil so that the case pattern is not transferred to the replacement.
3. You need to quote the cons cell `(myfun . nil)`, otherwise it will be interpreted as a function call and evaluated too early.

Here is a working version:

```lisp
(let ((case-fold-search nil))
  (perform-replace "<\\([^>]+\\)>"
                   `(,(lambda (data count)
                       (downcase (match-string 0))))
                   t t nil))
```

Comment: nop, I need the query (y/n/! etc.) and highlight capabilities of perform-replace (an I'd prefer not to reimplement it with y-or-n-p + highlight-regexp or similar)

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reflect this constraint. Anyways, I proposed a solution based on `perform-replace` which should fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`C-h f perform-replace` says:

```
Don't use this in your own program unless you want to query and set the mark
just as `query-replace' does.  Instead, write a simple loop like this:

  (while (re-search-forward "foo[ \t]+bar" nil t)
    (replace-match "foobar"))
```

Now the `"<\\,(downcase \1)>"` needs to be replaced by an Elisp expression that builds the proper string, such as `(format "<%s>" (downcase (match-string 1)))`.

If you do need the query and stuff, then you might like to try: `C-M-% f\(o\)o RET bar \,(downcase \1) baz RET` and then `C-x RET RET` to see what arguments were constructed during the interactive call.

You'll see discover (even better if you click on `replace.el` in `C-h f perform-replace` to see the source code of the function), that the `replacements` argument can take the form (FUNCTION . ARGUMENT).  More specifically, the code includes a comment giving some details:

```
;; REPLACEMENTS is either a string, a list of strings, or a cons cell
;; containing a function and its first argument.  The function is
;; called to generate each replacement like this:
;;   (funcall (car replacements) (cdr replacements) replace-count)
;; It must return a string.
```

Comment: `emacs -Q` -> `C-x RET RET is undefined`