# Emacs: replace-regexp replacement not changing case

Tags: regex, emacs

I was recently trying to convert exported Common Lisp symbols from strings to keywords. I basically wanted `"HELLO"` to become `:hello`. I tried using the Emacs replace-regexp command. Here are the two expressions I gave it:

```
"\([^ ]*\)"
:\,(downcase \1)
```

I tested the first one by checking if it would find all of the cases I wanted it to replace and it did. However, when I went through with the replacement, it worked *except* the symbols were not lowercase (`"HELLO"` became `:HELLO`). I then tried changing the first expression into a case by case one. Something along the lines of:

```
"\([-A-Z+*/\<>=&]*\)"
```

Oddly enough when I used the same second expression with this new first expression, it worked perfectly. Is this a bug, or am I actually doing something wrong?

Comment: I couldn't make it work on regex101.com but take a look at regex conversion http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html

Comment: See #2 of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13706627/319698

Comment: npostavs, you are right, thank you. It is just such a weird default. @Fede, you need to run it in Emacs since the replacement expression has elisp code in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour of `replace-regexp`, see its docstring:

`` Preserve case in each match if `case-replace' and `case-fold-search'
are non-nil and REGEXP has no uppercase letters. ``

So to avoid case preservation, you may either include upper case letters in the matching regexp, or <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>set-variable</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>case-replace</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>nil</kbd>. (You could also set `case-fold-search`, but that affects a lot of searching functions, whereas `case-replace` only affects replacing functions).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706627/319698 for the non-interactive version of this.